# IText Sharp extract text from pdf with French Script MT

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, itext, text-extraction

I am using ITextSharp and listed code to extract text from pdf.
But I have found that some rows give me incorrect result:

1. in excel - "11  3 11"
2. in Visual Studio - "11 \u0085\u0014\u0016\u001c 3 11"
3. in pdf - "11 £139 3 11"

One more example:

1. in excel - "2  45 1"
2. in Visual Studio - "2 \u0085\u0019\u0018\u001b 45 1"
3. in pdf - "2 £658 45 1"

After investigation I have found that pdf file contains 
french-script-mt-58fbba579ea99.ttf

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pfile.path)){
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
if (pagenum == 0)
{
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
string page = "";
page = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new 
iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
string stringOutput = page;
string[] lines = stringOutput.Split('\n');
allData.Add(lines);
output = lines;
}
}
}
```

## Questions:

1. How I can add font that I have loaded to Extract strategy?
2. Is it possible to create mapping so I can convert \u0085\u0014\u0016\u001c to £139?
3. Maybe I have missed something with encoding?

Comment: Can you share the pdf for inspection? And how exactly is excel related to the pdf?

Comment: Here is part of pdf file (it will be online for 30 days)
[pdfFile](https://ufile.io/ce0yy)
I have created parser for pdf files thus I can Analyze data and structure itself, I just put all parsed text to Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.
And this French text is bottleneck of my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the entries with the pound currency symbol "£" are drawn using fonts (named **C2_0** and **C2_2** respectively) without the information required for PDF text extraction as described in the PDF specification ISO 32000-1 section 9.10 "Extraction of Text Content": They use encoding **Identity-H** (which does not imply any mapping to Unicode) and have no **ToUnicode** mapping.

The fonts used for the other entries either use a meaningful encoding (**T1_0** and **T1_1** use **WinAnsiEncoding**) or have a **ToUnicode** map (**C2_1**).

As text extraction in iText essentially follows the description in that section 9.10, iText cannot extract the actual text of these £-entries, instead it returns the raw glyph codes, just like Adobe Reader copy&paste does.

Usually this means that one has to resort to OCR, either to the page as a whole and extract all text using OCR, or to the characters of the fonts in question individually to build **ToUnicode** tables for those fonts and then extract the text as above.

In this case, though, the **C2_0** and **C2_2** embedded font programs themselves contain information mapping the contained glyphs to Unicode code points. Thus, one can also build **ToUnicode** tables making use of the information in those font programs. Such information can be read from the font programs using a font library which can handle true type fonts.

Comment: Hi mkl!
Thank you a lot! Your answer somehow resolve my issue.
I will use Adobe as main tool and ITextSharp for structure analysis.
And I will better create parser based on Adobe output or any other OCR.

Comment: Also, can you please share about what tools you used to inspect above information?

Comment: @Vitalii I used RUPS, a PDF inspection tool based on iText, and I had a copy of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) open for reference.